# Export Html table to EXCEL , PDF , Print

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will export my html table to pdf , excel and print 
I found this tuto ,  I try it but not work 
I think I missing something
I need help 
[tuto link ] https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: show us what you tried? Paste some code snippet here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3F8ZJ/

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3F8ZJ/

Make sure you check the versions.
Make sure to load this CDN's

```
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js
http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css
http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js
```

Comment: thx for reponse
i check your post in jsfiddle but is not work export pdf excel :/
please help me i need this

Comment: @SarraPapoAlaa just try it out. It will work, dunno what's issue with JSFiddle, as its loaded in iFrame it's blocking

Comment: for me not work 
i need any example for 3 btn 
1 export pdf
2 export Excel
3 print
if you have samthing like that help me please

Answer (score 0):

Table Tools, that you are using, has now been retired and has been replaced by the Buttons and Select extensions.I wouldn't recommend using it.

Also, try using HTML buttons instead of SWF, unless you have to.

I made some changes to your code, and it is working well. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3F8ZJ/133/)!

```
Note that, i have changed external resources
```

Also i would recommend using local resources instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

You might study programming skills and make a code.

As an easier way, I introduce an online extracting tool, http://listly.io/.
Copy and Paste your html code, then it extracts the list-like contents.
You can also download Excel file.